# Remote Desktop from Windows to Mac which actually works

Tags: macos, windows-8, mac, remote-desktop, vnc

I need to work on both Windows 8 and Mac Mavericks, Windows 8 being my main machine.

I've been trying to do a remote desktop from Windows 8.1 to Mac.
I tried different solutions VNC, TightVNC, TeamViewer.
None of them worked well.

With VNC ones, refresh rate is pretty bad. 
Walking through the menus in a Mac app doesn't refresh.
I tried to play a bit with connection settings with no luck. 
If someone has specific settings I should apply, that could help.

With TeamViewer it worked good, but the problem is the CPU usage on Mac is very high.

Ironically, the only good way I found is to work the other way, I'm connecting from Mac to Windows using Microsoft's Remote Desktop for Mac app, which works perfectly.

Comment: `I'm connecting from Mac to Windows using Microsoft's Remote Desktop for Mac app, which works perfectly`...so what is the issue now??

Comment: per the title, the issue is I want to connect from Windows to Mac

Answer (score 0):

The CPU problem on team viewer seems to be only on newer versions of team viewer. So, if you downgrade to an older version, this may solve the problem.

Older versions are available [here](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/dyngate.aspx#version8).

Comment: thanks, I see what you mean, but isn't there any other way than downloading to an earlier version?

Comment: Not that I know of, but it only needs to be downgraded on the device you are connecting to (in your case, the mac). You can connect to an older version of team viewer with a newer version

Comment: it's 2015, it's kind of sad I have to download to an ealier version of something just to have a normal CPU usage; there has to be an easier way